# Why are we feeding the data pair by pair within a session?

Tags: tensorflow, linear-regression

As we can see in the code below, we are running the optimizer within a for loop of pair of x and y from the training data set. My question is why are we feeding the data to the optimizer pair by pair? How can an optimizer ran just on one pair of x and y?

```
    for (x, y) in zip(train_X, train_Y):
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})
```

Comment: whats your `train_X, train_Y` shapes?

Comment: @AlexK, They're both (30,)

Comment: Are they just.. array of 30 primitive type values or they are generators or some kind of data class?

Comment: they are 30 primitive type values. sorry I didn't specify this.